# change text size together with plot size in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change my plot size smaller (3,2) but I have an issue that my text (axis label, legend, axis title) don't change their sizes. Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (3,2), facecolor = 'w')
plt.axis([1985,2015,2,30])
plt.plot(new_time_list1,new_head_list1,linestyle='',marker='o',markerfacecolor='red',label="observed")
plt.plot(new_time_list2,new_head_list2,color='green',label=headers[i])
plt.ylabel('Water levels (mAHD)',fontsize = 2)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize = 2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=2)
plt.savefig(headers[i]+'.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(),edgecolor = 'k')
```

Is there anyway to make my text size changed automatically corresponding to plot size.

Comment: you want to use 2pt font?

Comment: Perhaps using named size could autosize with plot: http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties I didn't tested thou

Comment: 2pt font is just my test. b/c when I changed my plot size to (3,2), it gave me the graph with all the text in big size compare to the size of the plot. I don't know how to resize everything together. I tried to resize label separately but it didn't have any effect on my graph.